# Pre-rendering angularJS app using PhantomJS for SEO

Tags: javascript, angularjs, seo, phantomjs

I have a web site developed in AngularJS that I need to be crawl-able by Google, so I followed this tutorial: http://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/11/angularjs-and-seo.html

All well and good, but the HTML it outputs still has ng-repeat directives and the filters do not seem to be working:

Regardless of what termId I use all the items are shown instead of the filtered list.

Is this even possible as the filtering happens once the page is completely loaded?

Comment: Are you setting a 'status' message in the DOM once all your AngularJS code (including filtering) has completed?
http://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/11/angularjs-and-seo.html#sptting-out-the-html-pages

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Page is not completely loaded/rendered when onLoadFinished fires](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27260702/page-is-not-completely-loaded-rendered-when-onloadfinished-fires)