# Page is not completely loaded/rendered when onLoadFinished fires

Tags: javascript, angularjs, phantomjs

I'm using Phantomjs to examine my application. The page I am looking at includes a lot of components and is powered by Angularjs. My test server is slow. In the `onLoadFinished` event, I am imaging the web page using render:

```
page.onLoadFinished = function(response) {
    console.log(response, page.url);
    if (page.url.indexOf("login") == -1) {
        page.render('zoot.png');
        phantom.exit();
    }
};
```

My issue is that `zoot.png` only includes the site's menu bar. The menu bar's text and static images are rendered but the icons are Xs. The main page area is blank. A textual version number appears in the lower right which is expected.

It looks like the page was not fully drawn when the `render` happened.  Is there another event that means "done and ready for use"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might find a way [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14968690/sending-event-when-angular-js-finished-loading) to register an event when angular has finished rendering, but it might not be necessary if you are willing to wait a static amount of time:

```
page.onLoadFinished = function(response) {
    console.log(response, page.url);
    if (page.url.indexOf("login") == -1) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            page.render('zoot.png');
            phantom.exit();
        }, 1000);
    }
};
```

You can also use [`waitFor`](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/waitfor.js) to explicitly wait for the appearance of a selector which denotes the end of the load.

Note that `page.open(url);` and `page.onLoadFinished = finishedFunction;` is the same as `page.open(url, finishedFunction)`.

Comment: Thank you!  I don't know if that's the right answer but it will certainly allow me to verify my suspicion that the page has not completed loading. If I wait several seconds and nothing changes there is a different issue.

Comment: You can also use [`waitFor`](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/waitfor.js) if you don't want to wait a static amount of time.

Comment: I waited for 10 seconds. Nothing changed. I suspect I am not handling a redirect.

Comment: But if there would be a redirect problem, nothing would have shown up on the screenshot, am I right? Please register to the [`onConsoleMessage`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-console-message.html), [`onError`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-error.html), [`onResourceError`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-error.html), [`onResourceTimeout`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-timeout.html) events. Maybe there are errors.

Comment: PhantomJS' onConsoleMessage() reported an error that does not occur in Chrome (the site works fine). The issue involved something in the browser history not being initialized. The solution was the generally harmless `a.b = a.b || {};`  I do not yet know what code path I took to get to a state where `a.b` was undefined, but that is beyond my question.  Thank you again!