# JavaScript scraping - Coursera

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs

I am trying to scrappe coursera webpage using PhantomJS. However when I try to do that it is unable to display the actual content instead it only shows loading. When we try to access [coursera](http://www.coursera.org) you can see an intermediate display showing loading and this is being shown. However since phantomJS is a headless browser should'nt it be able to retrieve the source code exactly as what a browser would do? I tried setting the timeouts, useragents but to no avail. Any pointers?

EDIT:
Please find the code snippet for simple scrapping:

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var system = require('system');
var page = webPage.create();
page.settings.resourceTimeout = 5000; // 5 seconds
var url = system.args[1];

page.open(url, function (status) {
        if(status === 'success') {
        var content = page.content;
        console.log(content);
        phantom.exit();
        }
        else
        {console.log("Error!")
        phantom.exit()
        }
    });
```

EDIT:

Been trying this a bit more but still no luck. (Just wondering if OP tried this further with any luck)

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.settings.resourceTimeout = 10000; // 5 seconds
page.settings.userAgent   = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36';
var system = require('system');
var fs = require('fs');

if(system.args.length !== 3) {
  console.log('Usage: phantomjs text-scraper.js <url> <output file>');
  phantom.exit();
}

var url = system.args[1];
var outfile = system.args[2];


page.open(url);
//page.open(url, function(status) {
  //var output = url + '\n';
  //console.log(output);
  //if(status === 'success') {
page.onLoadFinished = function(msg) {
      var text = page.evaluate(function () {
        return document.title + '\n' + document.body.innerText;
      });
    console.log(text);
      //output += text;
      //fs.write(outfile, output);
      //phantom.exit()
  //} else {
  //  console.log("Error!")
    phantom.exit();
  //}
  //}
};
```

Comment: use greaseomnkey or tampermonkey to scrape; they run all the latest stuff, you can see what you're doing, and it just needs a browser instead of a node box.

Comment: I see, I will try that. But those are just for analyzing?

Comment: what do you mean by "just for analyzing"? anything you see in the browser you can collect, organize, filter, and save using the "monkeys". to wit; https://github.com/rndme/download can put physical files on the local machine from a string that a monkey makes from html on any url.

Comment: Could you show the code you have so far? Thanks.

Comment: Please register to the [`onConsoleMessage`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-console-message.html), [`onError`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-error.html), [`onResourceError`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-error.html), [`onResourceTimeout`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-timeout.html) events. Maybe there are errors. Also, don't forget to add your code into the question.

Comment: None of them registered any errors. I tried all of the above events

Comment: possible duplicate of [Page is not completely loaded/rendered when onLoadFinished fires](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27260702/page-is-not-completely-loaded-rendered-when-onloadfinished-fires)